# What is the correct procedure for installing c3 for use in webpack project with ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-modules, c3.js

I have a very simple webpack project with uses Html plugin to generate a html file from a single js file entry.

I installed c3 with "npm install c3"

chart.js

```
import * as c3 from "c3";

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
```

when i load the page i have an error:

```
bootstrap:893 TypeError: c3.generate is not a function
    at chart.js:5
    at chart.js:14
__webpack_require__.oe @ bootstrap:893
Promise.catch (async)
./client/chart.js @ chart.js:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:769
fn @ bootstrap:129
6 @ module.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:769
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:907
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:907
chart.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c3.generate is not a function
    at chart.js:5
    at chart.js:14
(anonymous) @ chart.js:5
(anonymous) @ chart.js:14
Promise.catch (async)
./client/chart.js @ chart.js:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:769
fn @ bootstrap:129
6 @ module.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:769
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:907
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:907
```

my package.json contains

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/c3": "^0.7.4",
    "c3": "^0.7.12",
```

Any advice is very much appreciated. c3js.org gives no instruction how to npm install and use with ES6 imports.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

fixed:

-import * as c3 from 'c3'

+import c3 from 'c3'